# C++ error(converting wstring to string): cannot convert argument 1 from std::wchar_t to std::char

Tags: c++, string, similarity, wstring

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <math.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

/*
* dice coefficient = bigram overlap * 2 / bigrams in a + bigrams in b
* (C) 2007 Francis Tyers
* Modifications made by Stefan Koshiw 2010
* Now it outputs values [0..1]
* Released under the terms of the GNU GPL.
*/


float dice_coefficient(wstring string1, wstring string2);


void main()
{
    float dice = 0;
    wstring str1(L"save");
    wstring str2(L"gave");

    dice = dice_coefficient(str1, str2);
    cout << dice;
}


float dice_coefficient(wstring string1, wstring string2)
{

    set<string> string1_bigrams;
    set<string> string2_bigrams;

    //base case
    if (string1.length() == 0 || string2.length() == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (string1.length() - 1); i++) {      // extract     character bigrams from string1
        string1_bigrams.insert(string1.substr(i, 2));
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (string2.length() - 1); i++) {      // extract     character bigrams from string2
        string2_bigrams.insert(string2.substr(i, 2));
    }

    int intersection = 0;

    // find the intersection between the two sets

    for (set<string>::iterator IT = string2_bigrams.begin();
        IT != string2_bigrams.end();
        IT++)
    {
        intersection += string1_bigrams.count((*IT));
    }

    // calculate dice coefficient
    int total = string1_bigrams.size() + string2_bigrams.size();
    float dice = (float)(intersection * 2) / (float)total;

    return dice;
}
```

in above codes, "string1_bigrams.insert(string1.substr(i, 2));" and "string1_bigrams.insert(string1.substr(i, 2));" does not work.
I used Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. The system said " cannot convert from 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called"
Please tell me how can i fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest workaround is to convert `set<string>` to `set<wstring>`:

```
set<wstring> string1_bigrams;
set<wstring> string2_bigrams;

.
.
.

for (set<wstring>::iterator IT = string2_bigrams.begin();
```

And also, you should return `int` for the main function.

See [demo](https://ideone.com/LlbbfG).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `std::set<wstring>` as [M M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952747/m-m) suggested, IF you can/want.

If you cannot for any reason... you may use this:

```
//string1_bigrams.insert(string1.substr(i, 2));
string1_bigrams.insert(&string1[i], &string1[2]);
```

Also you should consider passing the function parameters as reference, otherwise your hardcoded-constructed strings in your main function will be copied and passed to the function.

```
float dice_coefficient(std::wstring &string1, std::wstring &string2)
```